# mongodb case insensitive index for 3.4 version

Tags: node.js, mongodb, indexing

I have created a collection say users, example documents like given below

```
[{

"name" : "John", 
"code" : "B7"
},
{

"name" : "Sara", 
"code" : "F7"
}]
```

I have created one index on field "name"

```
db.users.createIndex(
 { name: 1 },
 { 
  collation: {locale: "en", strength: 1},
  unique: true
 }
)
```

I want to prevent duplicate case insensitive data for name field for example it will not allow entry for name "jOhn" or "jOHn" like that.
It's working but when I'm inserting data in mongodb is giving error messages 
Inserted data given below

```
db.users.insert([{ "name" : "JoHn", "code" : "B9" }])
```

Error message given below

```
{
"message" : "WriteError({'code':11000,'index':0,'errmsg':'E11000 duplicate key error collection: digital_data_delivery.users index: name_1 dup key: { : \\';E7C\\' }','op':{'name':'JoHn','code':'B9','_id':'5b4836a458abe34b442a9811'}})",
"stack" : "script:1:10"
}
```

Some junk characters are coming here "E7C" I want to know what is this

Comment: Junk characters are not coming from separate code, I'm  using below code for inserting db.users.insert([{
 "name" : "JoHn",
 "code" : "B9"
}])

Comment: I see what you mean now, the dup key value in the message doesn't match up with with actual duplicated key. Weird.